# VS2008 C++ "interface" as a parameter name fails to compile

Tags: c++, visual-c++

As the title says, I'm getting a compiler error in a VS2008 C++ program.  I'm not sure how better to describe my problem than in code.  The following compiles unless I uncomment the TEST line.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//#define TEST //<-- uncomment for error
#ifdef TEST
void test(void* interface)
{
    return;
}
#endif
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return(0);
}
```

When uncommented I get the following errors:

```
1>main.cpp(7) : error C2332: 'struct' : missing tag name
1>main.cpp(7) : error C2144: syntax error : '<unnamed-tag>' should be preceded by ')'
1>main.cpp(7) : error C2144: syntax error : '<unnamed-tag>' should be preceded by ';'
1>main.cpp(7) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>main.cpp(8) : warning C4094: untagged 'struct' declared no symbols
1>main.cpp(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>main.cpp(8) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

This is unmanaged code, so I'm not sure what the issue with the word interface is.  Is there any way to get this code to compile as is, or do I have to change every instance of the term interface to something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299565/how-to-disable-interface-keyword-on-visual-c-express-2008)

Comment: I tried looking for dups, but didn't see that one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code needs to include `Windows.h` then you should avoid using the name `interface` as it's reserved for the use that the Windows SDK has reserved for it (essentially it's a synonym for the keyword `struct`).  There are probably hacks to work around that problem (you could `#undef interface` after including the SDK headers), but you should probably avoid using that identifier.

Answer (score 2):

The word `interface` is reserved by MSVC++, as it is a non-standard `keyword` added by Microsoft Compiler, which is used to define *interface* in MSVC++.

So use a different name for the parameter, something like this:

```
#ifdef TEST
void test(void* test_interface)
{
    return;
}
#endif
```

Comment: I upvoted, but marked Michael Burr's answer as correct, since #undef was a better solution for me.  I'm trying to compile an existing library in MSVC, so changing the parameters names isn't a good solution.