# How to compile program that contains "interface" as variable name in Visual Studio 2013+

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

It seems that in last Visual Studio `interface` is now a keyword of some sort. I don't really know why, neither I can find such a keyword in C++ or C++11 standard, but using variable with name "interface" produces following error:

```
error C2332: 'struct' : missing tag name
```

Renaming the variables from `interface` to something like `my_interface` fixed the problem, but isn't there a way to compile it without having to modify the code?

Comment: You could add `#define interface my_interface` in your project settings

Comment: that might fix it, but isn't there some compiler option that disable this keyword which isn't standard?

Comment: Try to deactivate extension in visual (`/Za`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299565/how-to-disable-interface-keyword-on-visual-c-express-2008

Comment: Seems to be as easy as using `#undef interface`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `interface` is *not* a [C++ keyword defined by the standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword), it is an [extension in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/737cydt1.aspx) (which goes all the way back to VS2005 as far as I know). This will therefore not compile on other compilers if they do not have such an extension, in which case you must remove it.

The various ways to declare an interface in a C++ standard manner [are described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318064/how-do-you-declare-an-interface-in-c)

**Edit**
It seems I misunderstood your question, and you instead want to use variables named `interface` without Visual Studio thinking you are declaring an interface.

In that case, compile with the [/Za flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) to disable compiler extensions.

Comment: I probably didn't form the question properly. My problem is not with using "interface" anywhere else. My problem is that the code is already using this variable name "interface" somewhere and thus doesn't compile in Visual Studio where it's a keyword. The source code is perfectly valid according to standards and cross compile everywhere, except for last Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's an extension of visual studio for C++:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/737cydt1.aspx

Try to disable language extension (by passing a /Za):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx